# How to Extrude Circle Inwards Evenly?

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

I have this circle that I am trying to extrude evenly, but it doesn't extrude properly.

I pressed <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, then when I drag in it go slightly at a downward angle.

[image]

I am following a tutorial and for some reason my <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> doesn't extrude evenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the 3D cursor at the center of the circle (in *Object* mode you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* if the origin of your circle is still at its middle, or in *Edit* mode select the 2 extremities of your arc and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*), choose the 3D cursor as *Transform Pivot Point*, and scale the extrusion:

[image]

[image]

Comment: should i always have it set to 3D cursor for everything I make or just for this example?

Comment: just for this example, most of the time leave it to the default setting which is Median Point

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is used to scale geometry along the normal, if it behaves like this when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> it's because your normals are facing that way.
I don't know what is the tutorial and I don't know what you did differently compared to it but normally if you have a circle, the normals of each vertex should be pointing to the center of the circle so even when you delete half of the circle, you should still probably have this when you extrude and do <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> :

[image]

So the best solution for you would be to start over, create a new circle and delete half of it but if, for some reason, you can't redo everything from the beginning, you can do the following :

Select the two vertices at both end of your half circle

[image]

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> choose `Cursor to Selected` :

[image]

it will snap your cursor at the center of your circle. Then, change the pivot point to 3D cursor :

[image]

Then, press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the vertices and it will scale them according to the 3D cursor :

[image]